# "Run as Administrator" context menu item missing after upgrade from XP to 7

Tags: windows-7, uac, elevated, windows-7-upgrade

I have upgraded from XP pro to 7 ultimate (32bit)

If I leave UAC settings default, I have no "Run as Administrator" menu item in the contextual right-click menu onto an executable. Additionally, programs that need elevated privileges aren't unable to get them (procexp, processhacker - they also miss the re-launch as admin item in their menus)

If I turn off UAC, I am able to launch stuff as admin as the user is member in the administrators group (procexp or processhacker have the admin-specific features active - such as disk monitoring)

I blame the upgrade process (was an true upgrade with keeping settings, files etc)

Attempts like [running sfc](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/run-as-administrator-option-missing) or [adding registry settings](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/200558-run-administrator-add-remove-context-menu-windows-7-a.html) made no change. The only workaround I could find so far is to type a valid executable path or name in the start menu search field, then after selecting the hilighted result, press ctrl-shift-enter, which results in launching the app with elevated privileges (with elevated prompt GUI dialog confirmation).

However, I need the GUI clic-click menu item, how do I get it back?

Comment: This a local user or a user on a domain?  We need specifics.

Comment: [Windows 7: Run as Administrator - Add or Remove from Context Menu in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/200558-run-administrator-add-remove-context-menu-windows-7-a.html)

Comment: Try holding down `SHIFT` and `right-clicking` too for a potential quick solution to get the `Run As Administrator` option... It may work for your immediate need at least.

Comment: @DavidPostill been there, done that, just forgot to mention it. has no effect.

Comment: @Ramhound: local user, no domain, no group policies

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish: tried that, but result is that holding down shift while right clicking enables the "run as a different user" menu, NOT the "run as administrator"

Comment: @CostinGușă Go to services (`Services.msc`) and make sure the service `Secondary Logon` is running and is set to `Automatic` startup. Start or restart that service and then see if the option is there with the right click or hold down shoft with the right click.

Comment: @1Fish_2Fish_RedFish_BlueFish, secondary logon service is the nt/2000/xp old-style service responsible for "run as" another user gui interface; for user account control elevation prompt ("run as administrator"), the Application Information Service is in charge, which is enabled and started. Actually, you can even have the secondary service stopped and UAC still works. See http://techfilth.blogspot.com/2012/05/uh-oh-dont-stop-application-information.html and http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-and-around-windows-vista-user-account-control/ for how UAC works

Comment: @CostinGușă Something has to be missing from the registry or something then I would think. If you tried adding the reg keys manually, looking at UAC settings, running SFC, etc. then you may simply have corruption that cannot be resolved. This is the very reason I personally NEVER do an upgrade from OS version to OS version as you'll have more chance for corruption and old OS files, etc. lingering around. It's much cleaner to just install the new OS fresh. If you must upgrade from an older OS per licensing, install clean fresh XP and then upgrade without years of data on it. Out of other ideas.